# Can the NIC ucarp uses be bridged?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, failover, ucarp

I have setup ucarp failover using [this](http://www.pytips.com/2010/3/16/ip-failover-with-ucarp-on-ubuntu) howto, and it works great.

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.200.0.102
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        ucarp-vid 3
        ucarp-vip 10.200.0.200
        ucarp-password ourpassword
        ucarp-advskew 10
        ucarp-advbase 1
        ucarp-master yes

iface eth0:ucarp inet static
      address 10.200.0.200
      netmask 255.255.255.255
```

Somewhere told me that I should not use (in this case) `10.200.0.102` for anything, as it could have influence on ucarp's ability to failover.

Would it be possible to bridge `eth0`, so I can get an extra IP to use for SSH, rsync and things like that without affecting ucarp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add:

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address   10.200.0.103
    netmask   255.255.255.0
    ucarp-vid 3
    ucarp-vip 10.200.0.200
    ucarp-password ourpassword
    ucarp-advskew 10
    ucarp-advbase 1
    ucarp-master yes
iface eth0:1:ucarp inet static
    address 10.200.0.201
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

otherwise a more complete howto here:

http://ajohnstone.com/achives/running-several-vips-on-the-same-interface-with-ucarp-and-haproxy/

Comment: Incredible. That was just what I needed =) I assume `ucarp-vip` and the last `address` should be the same?